# Enter Text into Kendo Textbox with Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, protractor

I'm trying to use Protractor to enter text into a Kendo TextBox, but I get an error "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible". When you click on the text box, the "style="display: none;" changes to "style="display: inline-block;" if that helps.

```
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value k-input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;">
<input kendo-numeric-text-box="" k-options="numericConfig" k-ng-model="somemodel" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" class="k-input" type="text" aria-valuenow="323423" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;">
```

How would I sendKeys to this text box?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand after looking at the [kendo numeric box input demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index), you need to first click the visible input, then send keys to the one that would become visible after:

```
element(by.css("input.k-input")).click();
element(by.css("input[kendo-numeric-text-box]")).sendKeys("10");
```